# Bug while deploying Azure TSI preview?

Tags: azure, azure-timeseries-insights

I'm trying to setup an instance of Azure time series insight with a PAYG(preview) tier. But this is the result I get: 
[image]

It seems that the deployment wasn't successful after all. Even though it worked while following the tutorial from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/time-series-insights/time-series-insights-update-create-environment). When I try "Go to environment", I get notified that I'm "Unable to open the uri. Please try again later.".

Other colleagues tried and got the same result. Is this a bug? Or did we miss something?

Any help or news would be welcome.

Thank you

Quentin

Comment: Can you try again by clearing browser cookies, cache and history? Also, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/time-series-insights/tutorial-create-populate-tsi-environment if you are missing any steps.

Comment: In the mean time, the problem got resolved without me doing anything, so I guess it was the service being updated? And the link you sent me is for the GA while I'm figuring out the PAYG version. Anyway, do you know of a place where I can see what might not work with the current build of the service? Because I have few problems with the API's. And I really don't know what I might be doing wrong. Thank you